# in what interval the nonlinear ode has infinite many solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following initial problem :
$$x'(t)=x^{\frac{2}{3}},x\in [0,\alpha]$$
with an initial condition :
$$x(0)=-1$$
My question is what kind of $\alpha$, this IVP can have infinitely many solutions. Moreover, what will happen if we change the initial condition to $x(0)=0$ or $x(0)=1$.

My attempting:
First I find a class of solutions (may or may not be the general solution, since it is a nonlinear equation):
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{27}(t-3)^3$$

then I found $x'(3)=0,x(3)=0$, so if $\alpha>3$, we can cut the point (3,0), i.e 
$$x(t)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{27}(t-3)^3,t\in[0,3)\\
0,t\in [3,\alpha-\epsilon)\\
\frac{1}{27}(t-\alpha)^3,x\in[\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha]\\
\end{cases}$$

and $\epsilon$ can have infinity many choices, such we have infinity many solutions in the interval $[0,\alpha]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions provided $\alpha$ is greater than the first zero of the solution (which is unique even though the solutions themselves are not). I didn't check your work to see that this zero is at $3$, however.

This is still true if you start at zero (because then you can just do this "stay flat and then increase at an arbitrary later time" trick right away).

This isn't true going *forward in time* if you start from a positive value, because the solutions for this equation are uniquely determined by the interval in which they are equal to zero.

Comment: are there any deeper theorems behind this problem? like for general initial value problem?

Comment: @DuFong Basically it is just the usual existence/uniqueness while the system is currently not at zero. At zero itself the conventional theory breaks down (because you lose the Lipschitz property) and you need to do more *ad hoc* analysis.